# Uninstall all the packages which are installed?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, software-installation, uninstall, software-uninstall

I had installed some packages into fresh created Ubuntu machine, i want to uninstall all the packages which i had installed from the day of beginning(i.e. from 12 hours back)  and make the system like newly created.

Answer (score 1):

See `/var/log/apt/history.log` for a complete listing of installed packages, with time stamps and commands. Start at the end and work your way backwards.

Comment: Note that this also shows the packages which were installed during installation, so one must carefully look at the timestamps to avoid uninstalling any essential packages. One may also require to look at the older archives of the log file saved as `history.log.<num>.gz` which are saved in same directory.

Comment: Exactly the same as I would have said!  So upvoted!  ;-)